# OSX, .local domains are not resolved

Tags: macos, dns, hostname, bonjour, mdns

I am running a webserver on my Mac with OSX 10.9. In our LAN my IP is connected to example.local, so that everybody in the LAN should access my webserver.

Unfortunately, the .local doamin is not resolved correctly from my Mac. As far as I could find out is probably due to the Bonjour service, which claims to be the .local domains.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix, add example.local to a line in your /etc/hosts file:

127.0.0.1  example.local

Comment: Tanks, this was too easy :D